# How to update PostgreSQL db with a triple join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables (`a`,`b`,`c`). I want to update a column in table `a` (named `email`) where
`a.id = b.id, b.name = c.name`.

This is what I have so far.

```
UPDATE a
SET email = "hi@gmail.com"
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
        INNER JOIN c ON b.name = c.name
WHERE email IS NULL;
```

However I'm getting the error that table name `a` is specified more than once.

What can I do?

Comment: You need to alias the a table inside your from/joins and use that alias where you have Update a   now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the table being updated in the `from` clause.  Use the `where` clause to correlated it:

```
UPDATE a
    SET email = 'hi@gmail.com'
    FROM b JOIN
         c
         ON b.name = c.name
    WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.email IS NULL;
```